# How come Gradle appcompat-v7 error even though the version of the targeSdkVersoin is the same at 24?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-appcompat

[image: This is the error when I hover above it]

The app runs when I build it, and works fine. But I want to solve this problem, cause it may cause problem in the future. The picture shows the error when I hover on it. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

And I'm confused as to why it found two version 24.2.1 and 24.0.0, why is this? Which version is the right one?

Thank You

**UPDATE**

I run `gradlew app:dependencies` on the terminal and found this, 
if you look at the botton and found this `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0` *(at the bottom)*:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 24.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:10.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:10.2.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:10.2.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.2.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:10.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.2.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- **com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0**
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 24.2.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0** -> 24.2.1 (*)
```

And if I follow the root of it and found `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0`, so I add it to the dependencies and change it to `compile com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.2.1`, and the error is gone now. Is this the right way of doing it? Btw, I run my app and there is no error(There app still runs before, eventhough there is an error in the gradle).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I'm confused as to why it found two version 24.2.1 and 24.0.0,

You have to use `gradlew app:dependencies`.

In this way you will find which libraries has the dependency with 24.2.1 and 24.0.0

Comment: I run the 'gradlew app:dependencies' on the terminal, and do a search on 'appcompat-v7:24.0.0' and found it. I have write an update on my fix. Is what I do the right way of doing it? The error is gone now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the libraries you are using depends on a specific AppCompat version but you  are referencing a different version in your own app.

Find out which library is doing this then exclude the AppCompat references that are causing the fault from the build.

e.g.

```
compile("com.your.libary:1.0.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'preference-v7'
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion of the quick way to find it? Thanks btw

Comment: have a look at the gradle files on the github pages for the libraries you are using